# Inverse of the map $(x,y)\mapsto\left(\frac{y^2}{x^2},\frac{y(2-x^2)}{x^2}\right)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, inverse-function

> How can I find the inverse of the map $\phi \colon E_1 \to E_2$ with $(x,y) \mapsto \left(\frac{y^2}{x^2},\frac{y(2-x^2)}{x^2}\right)$ where $E_1 : y^2 = x^3+3x^2+2x$ and $E_2 : y^2 = x^3-6x^2+x$?

Also, are the infinity points $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{O'}$, respectively, for both curves the same? $(0:1:0)$ (this is in preojective coordinate, don't know how to write in affine coordinates), I need $\phi^{-1}(\mathcal{O'})$.

Comment: why do you think there should be an inverse ?

Comment: @mercio you mean not every point is invertible ? Well there's a second part of the exercise, a map $\psi$ is given and one has to prove then $(\psi\circ\phi)(P)=2P$. So I think there is an inverse

Comment: I mean the map is not injective, so it's not possible to invert it. In fact it has degree $2$, one output correspond to two inputs.

Comment: @mercio OK maybe a partial inverse may exist ?

Comment: @user257 $\phi$ is not invertible since it's $2:1$, but it has a dual isogeny, and I guess this is what you are asked to find.